# __setattr__ breaking code?

Tags: python, setattr

Here's the code I have

```
class Human(object):
  def __init__(self, name, gender):
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    print 'Hi there, I am '+ self.name

  def ThankHeavens(self):
    return 'Thanks Gods!'

class Soldier(Human):
  def __init__(self, name, gender, rank):
    super(Soldier, self).__init__(name, gender)
    self.rank = rank
    print self.rank + ' reporting!'

class Officer(Soldier):
  def __init__(self, name, gender, rank, num_subordinates):
    super(Officer, self).__init__(name, gender, rank)
    self.num_subordinates = num_subordinates

  def __setattr__(self, rank, value):
    if rank not in ['lieutenant', 'captain', 'major', 'colonel', 'commander', 'admiral']:
      print 'Invalid officer rank'
    else:
      super(Officer, self).__setattr__(rank, value)
```

It breaks whenever I try to create an officer:

```
helo = Officer(name='Agathon',
               gender='m',
               rank='lieutenant',
               num_subordinates=0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw7.py", line 39, in <module>
    num_subordinates=0)
  File "hw7.py", line 20, in __init__
    super(Officer, self).__init__(name, gender, rank)
  File "hw7.py", line 14, in __init__
    super(Soldier, self).__init__(name, gender)
  File "hw7.py", line 7, in __init__
    print 'Hi there, I am '+ self.name
AttributeError: 'Officer' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Why doesn't it recognize the name I've entered when defining `helo`?

Comment: Why you override `__setattr__`? Maybe a better idea is to add some logic to `__init__` method in `Solider` or `officer` class.

Comment: Rather than using `setattr` to check for argument validity, you should use property setters.

Answer (score 5):

What you haven't posted is the two messages created by your `__setattr__`:

```
Invalid officer rank
Invalid officer rank
```

These come from following lines:

```
self.name = name
self.gender = gender
```

Since these fail, you cannot retrieve the name later:

```
 print 'Hi there, I am '+ self.name
```

Fix:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    if key == "rank" and value not in [.....]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `__setattr__` is called when any attribute of the `Officer` is set at any time in any way, including during initialization via the superclass `__init__`.

When `__setattr__` is called, `self` will be the `Officer` instance, `rank` will be the **name of the attribute being set**, and `value` will be the value desired for that attributed.

What you have done is make the `Officer` class such that it can have a `.lieutenant` etc. for values in your list, but not a `.rank` (or `.name` or `.gender`) - and you have not actually restricted the value of that attribute at all.

This is deeper magic than you were looking for; you clearly wanted to restrict the **values** used when setting **the `.rank` attribute specifically**. To do that, use a property.